# Print object with the same value from array of objects

Tags: javascript

Assuming my current object is this below:

```
{
    "name": 1
    "type": 2
    "kind": 2
}
```

I want to print all the objects in the array that have the same "type" as my current object, which is `2`.

```
[
{
   "name": 1
   "type": 2
   "kind": 3
},
{
   "name": 2
   "type": 2
   "kind": 1
},
{
   "name": 2
   "type": 1
   "kind": 3
}
]
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
[
{
   "name": 1
   "type": 2
   "kind": 3
},
{
   "name": 2
   "type": 2
   "kind": 1
}
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Array.prototype.filter()` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter)

Like `fullArray.filter(element => element.type == myObject.type)` or if you are still using ES5 `fullArray.filter(function(element) { return element.type == myObject.type; })`

Beware I’m not on a computer, so I can’t test the code.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is array [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) :

```
    let array = [
{
"name": 1,
"type": 2,
"kind": 3
},
{
"name": 2,
"type": 2,
"kind": 1
},
{
"name": 2,
"type": 1,
"kind": 3
}
]
let customFilteredArray = array.filter(data => data.type===2) //you can add your custom check
```

Here is [example](https://repl.it/repls/NeighboringDarkorchidTwintext) :

Answer (score 0):

To get the objects which has some particular value for a property from an array can be achieved using `Array.filter()` method. Use it like this:

```
let arr = [
"name": 1,
"type": 2,
"kind": 3
},
{
"name": 2,
"type": 2,
"kind": 1
},
{
"name": 2,
"type": 1,
"kind": 3
}
];

let filteredArr = arr.filter(item => item.type === 2);
```

The `filteredArr` will only have objects whose type is 2.
Hope this helps.